# How to transform the JSON response into a table in sheets

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, json.net

I'm sending a request to an API (in a Google Scripts), and I'm getting the response as a JSON text that looks like this:

```
[{"id":26319355,"name":"1. WAW -FIRST SESION","calendar":"Glovers
Click&Collect","duration":30,"isSeries":false,"slots":90,"slotsAvailable"
:89,"color":"#E3DE7D","price":"0.00","category":"WAW","description":"",
"calendarID":2978881,"serviceGroupID":2978881,"appointmentTypeID":10104780,
"calendarTimezone":"Europe\/Madrid","time":"2019-06-01T12:00:00+0200",
"localeTime":"June 1, 2019 12:00"},

{"id":26466803,"name":"1. WAW -FIRST SESION","calendar":"Glovers
Click&Collect","duration":30,"isSeries":false,"slots":90,"slotsAvailable"
:89,"color":"#E3DE7D","price":"0.00","category":"WAW","description":"",
"calendarID":2978881,"serviceGroupID":2978881,"appointmentTypeID":10104780,
"calendarTimezone":"Europe\/Madrid","time":"2019-06-07T14:00:00+0200",
"localeTime":"June 7, 2019 14:00"},
```

I want to paste this response as a table in my spreadsheet.

My script actually looks like this (where response is the response I get from the API request):

```html
function CheckAv(row,acuityid,check,url,apiusername,apisecretkey,ss) {
 
 var header = {
        "contentType": "application/json",
        "headers":{"Authorization" : " Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(apiusername + ":" + apisecretkey)},
        "method" : "GET"
      }
   
  muteHttpExceptions: true 
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, header);
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  var text = response.getResponseCode();
   
  Logger.log(text);
   
}
```

I assume it will be really easy but I can't find the solution.

Comment: By table do you mean putting each value of the text in a cell, or creating something like a [pivot table](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/pivot-tables)?

Comment: @Jescanellas Yes, putting each value of the text in a cell, with the correct headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cycle through your JSON structure and push each key and value to a specified row using the code below.

```
  json = [{your: "JSON", data: "goes"}, {in : "here"}]

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var rows = [],
      data;

    for (i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        for (j in json[i]) {   

          dataq = json[i][j];

          Logger.log(dataq);

          rows.push([j, dataq]);
    }
      dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, rows.length, 2);
      dataRange.setValues(rows);    
  }
```

Comment: Hi Rafa, thanks for your answer.
I guess that my JSON data needs to be `response` on my previous query, right?

I'm adding the code that you gave me but unfortunately, I'm not getting the data pasted, just nothing happens.

Comment: Are you using `response` or `JSON.parse(response.getContentText)` for the variable `json`? If you set `json` to the reponse you posted in the original question (though with the final `,` replaced with a `]`), it should output the data into the first sheet of the Spreadsheet it's bound to.

Comment: I just used `JSON.parse(response.getContentText)`and it worked!
The problem is that now i'm getting the headers in one column and the values in the following column so it looks like:

NAME - John
EMAIL - john@gmail.com
NAME - Mark
EMAIL - mark@gmail.com
....

What I need is to have the names of the category as a headers and the information filling in each header

Comment: Can you add the structure of the layout of how you want your spreadsheet to the original question? At the moment it's not too clear exactly how you want the sheet to be populated.